Dirty reads happening in RCSI in Azure SQL Server
Although my database isolation level is set to READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT, I am still getting dirty (uncommited) reads.
SELECT COUNT([random_string]) NoTx FROM [dbo].[IncTesting5];
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    INSERT INTO [IncTesting5] ([random_string]) VALUES ('UncommittedRow1'),('UncommittedRow2');
    SELECT COUNT([random_string]) NoHint FROM [dbo].[IncTesting5];
    SELECT COUNT([random_string]) WIthHint FROM [dbo].[IncTesting5] WITH (READUNCOMMITTED);
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

This query returns NoTx = 0, NoHint = 2, WIthHint =2. I would expect NoHint to equal 0.


Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.

The docs say that READ COMMITTERD "...specifies that statements cannot read data that has been modified but not committed by other transactions. This prevents dirty reads." - but you're reading data modified by your own transaction.

All those queries are in the same scope, so would have access to the data you just inserted.

The query with SELECT COUNT([random_string]) NoHint is part of the same transaction in which the INSERT occurs. SQL Server allows a transaction to see its own uncommitted changes, even under READ COMMITTED. This is known as statement-level read consistency, but within the scope of your transaction, your transaction's changes are visible.
Therefore, the query sees the uncommitted INSERT rows because they are part of the same transaction.
If the NoHint query were executed in a separate session while the transaction was uncommitted, it would not see the uncommitted rows because of the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT setting:

In above image Session A sees the uncommitted rows because they are part of the same transaction and Session B which is under READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT, sees only committed rows (ignoring Session A’s uncommitted changes).
